# Get node ID or URL in Twig on field level

Tags: theming

I have a field value, which I would like to link to the content (to the node itself, using it in a teaser).

How can I get the URL or at least the ID on field level, to create that link?

Comment: Do you mean the ID of the entity (node) that the field that's being rendered is attached to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The node in a field template is the parent entity you find in element['#object'], which you can use to build the path:

```
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node':  element['#object'].id}) }}
```

Comment: Would this also work if the same field is coincidentally  used by another entity type (Paragraph) at the same time? Not sure if this is possible at all...

Comment: You wouldn't put this code in a generic field.html.twig, but in a template name suggestion targeting a specific field. If you have the same field name in different entities you can still target the specific one by adding the entity type to the template name.

Answer (score 3):

Without preprocessing, directly in Twig:

```
{# get owner entity #}
{% set owner_entity = element['#object'] %}
{# render id #}
id = {{ element['#object'].id }}
{# render raw field value #}
field foo = {{ element['#object'].field_foo.0.value }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should maybe preprocess you the URL in place. Via [`template_preprocess_field`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.2.x) get the node ID, build the path alias, send it to Twig.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field__FIELD_NAME().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field__MYFIELD(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['element']['#entity_type'] === 'node') {
    $node = $variables['element']['#object'];
    $nid = $node->id();
    $variables['myurl'] = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/' . $nid);
  }
}
```

In `field.html.twig` then do:

```
{% if myurl %}
   <a href="{{ myurl }}">Kool Keith</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantage (e.g. security) including the URL via element['#object'] without preprocessing (like suggested in the answers above)?

Comment: @Benjamin – That's what I asked under @4k4's answer. I guess fields can be shared across entities (but not sure about that), then an additional check for `node` would be nice. But from a security point of view there's no difference.